Clarification of Theorem 3.7.5 (Non-homogeneous Poisson thinning) in Durrett's Probability book
In theore 3.7.5 of Durrett's probability: theory and examples (5th edition). He writes:
Suppose that in a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, we keep a point that lands
at $s$ with probability $p(s)$. Then the result is a nonhomogeneous Poisson process with rate
$\lambda p(s)$.
This statement is written in a super hand-wavy way. Could somebody clarify what he means?

If we keep each Poisson arrival with fixed probability $p$ and discard it with fixed probability $1-p$, and all our keep/discard decisions are independent, then the kept arrivals are a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $\lambda p$ , and the discarded arrivals are also a homogeneous Poisson process  but with rate $\lambda(1-p)$. When the keep/discard decisions have possibly variable probability, then the resulting processes have variable rate and thus are no longer eligible to be called homogenous processes.
